# Formatting dates python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to format dates in a dates vs value plot

```
import datetime as datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl

values = [3, 2, 5]
dates = [datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 30, 10, 56, 11, 889521),datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1, 6, 16, 11, 889521),datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 2, 12, 16, 11, 889521)]
fig=pl.figure()
graph = fig.add_subplot(111)
graph.plot(dates,values,'k-')
pl.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
pl.show()
```

gives the following : [image]

The dates are formatted `'%H:%M:%S'`.

How could I easily format it to `'%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S'` ?

I have read numerous answers using `num2dates` and so on, but can't find a more direct way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) on a `datetime` object.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> print datetime(2014,2,3,4,5,6).strftime("%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S")
```

Output:

```
03/02/14 - 04:05:06
```

Comment: I used this along with `xticks()` and `xticklabels()`, the issue is, when a lot of values need to be plotted (which is my case), the x axis gets overcrowded. If I don't specify the `xticks`, matplotlib automatically displays only a few dates, and keeps the plot clean.

Comment: The best advice that I can give for this type of situation since I do not use matplotlib is to read the documentation on the ticker format api for matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

Answer (score 0):

You could play with the value of nbins in [MaxNLocator](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig=pl.figure()
graph = fig.add_subplot(111)
graph.plot(dates,values,'k-')
graph.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S'))
graph.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=5))
pl.show()
```